# How to use JSON extractor using contain

Tags: jmeter

My response body is bit dynamic sometime it contain a particular variable called name as follow,

`"name": "MIBAUTMain Testing Site",` and sometime `"name": "Main Testing Site",` so my JSON extractor `$.namespaces[?(@.name=='Main Testing Site')].uuid` is failing if I put `$.namespaces[?(@.name=='MIBAUTMain Testing Site')].uuid`.

But `Main Testing Site` is common, is there any way I pass `Main Testing Site` in to JSON extractor that does it contain ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a [regular expression](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression) in conjunction with the [filter operator](https://github.com/json-path/JsonPath#operators) so it would match both cases:

```
$..[?(@.name =~ /.*Main Testing Site.*/i)].uuid
```

[image]

More information: [How to Use the JSON Extractor For Testing](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/json-extractor)

Comment: I missed regular expression can be an alternate option.